# Random java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: java, exception, jsf, response

I realize that there are a lots of questions relating to this topic but all are related to writing to the response and then doing a redirect/forward or something like that in a predictable and easily reproducible manner.

The problem I'm having is that one day a production app suddenly started raising this exception on random pages, 4 o 5 times a day. The stacktrace is below. 
The app is using myfaces 1.1.9, richfaces 3.1.4.GA, tomahawk 1.1.10 and deployed on tomcat 5.5.33. 
I've tried updating this libraries but the problem continues.

Apparently when the request come in, the response is already committed. I don't know why this is happening. Reading the tomcat source code, the only way this could be posible is if the recycle() method of the Response is not called. But every time I debug the app the method is called.
The same is happening whether the request is ajax or not.

I can't reproduce this bug so any help could be much appreciated.

Stacktrace for http requests:

```
19 Apr 2011 11:27:44,817 ERROR [http-8080-Processor44] (ExceptionFilter.java:42) - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:323)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.dispatch(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:222)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:108)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:216)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:146)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:147)
    at utils.CustomFacesServlet.service(CustomFacesServlet.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at presentacion.filters.AutorizacionFilter.doFilter(AutorizacionFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at presentacion.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at presentacion.filters.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

19 Apr 2011 11:27:44,818 ERROR [http-8080-Processor44] (StandardWrapperValve.java:260) - Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:433)
    at presentacion.filters.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Stacktrace for ajax requests:

```
13 Apr 2011 07:12:24,841 ERROR [http-8080-Processor48] (CustomFacesServlet.java:63) - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:323)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.dispatch(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.jsp.JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspTilesViewHandlerImpl.java:222)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:108)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:216)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.myfaces.custom.ppr.PPRLifecycleWrapper.render(PPRLifecycleWrapper.java:84)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:147)
    at utils.CustomFacesServlet.service(CustomFacesServlet.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at presentacion.filters.AutorizacionFilter.doFilter(AutorizacionFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at presentacion.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)

13 Apr 2011 07:12:24,842 ERROR [http-8080-Processor48] (StandardWrapperValve.java:260) - Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.reset(ResponseFacade.java:308)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:168)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at presentacion.filters.AutorizacionFilter.doFilter(AutorizacionFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at presentacion.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Comment: The error is at line 52 of your CustomFacesServlet `utils.CustomFacesServlet.service(CustomFacesServlet.java:52)`. Check what you have at line 52. Also, check your code at line 51 in `AutorizacionFilter#doFilter` method - seems there is a problem there too!

Comment: @Chuong: CustomFacesServlet only wrap the request in a Hibernate Session, doesn't touch the response. AutorizacionFilter is a Servlet Filter which handle authorization in the app, it does a redirect if the user is not authorized but doesn't write to the response. Besides when the error occurs the user is authorized (no redirects).

Comment: Without seeing the codes of your Servlet or Filter, I'm guessing that you're trying to do a `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect` instead of `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url)`. Also, turn on your debug in your IDE and post the codes where the above errors occurred. It would help to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and in my case was the http connector. It get exhaustes, but got no error about, just the `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

Solution: modify the `server.xml` in `$JBOSS_HOME/server/<environment>/deploy/jbossweb.sar/` and add the `acceptCount="1000"` and `maxThreads="500"` (this in my case).
Hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you've written more to the response output than it has buffer for. Once you've filled the response buffer the bytes begin to be streamed to the client. At that point you can't change the response to redirect because the HTTP response headers have already been sent to the client. Here are some options I can think of that you have to solve this:

1. Detect that you need to redirect sooner in the request processing.
2. Configure your servlet or filter that's handling this request to have a larger response buffer.
3. Write a filter that buffers more of the output (perhaps there's already a library for this).

I'd say that ideally you do #1, however I know that can be tricky at times. Option #2 can be difficult to find the right configuration option, if one even exists. The last option is somewhat of a blanket fix, although note that you'll additionally be delaying the first byte to the client. It should be fairly trivial to write, and I imagine there's already code out there to do it (can't think anything that includes it offhand though).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem is that I'm not doing any redirects. The exception is raised at random pages on simple JSF requests (POST and then forward). Besides from the log I can tell that the user tries to access the same page again after the error occurs and it works just fine. Thats why I can't reproduce the problem.